# How do I get the index in a VBA For Each Loop (programming with Excel)?

Tags: vba, excel

I am working with EXCEL VBA to process some data and here is what I want to make:

[image: I want to develop a function that can calculate out the values in the light-green area]

In this sheet, I want to create a function "GetDebutDate" that can automatically calculate the first date that the row has a value.

For example, in the row of "Mark", the first time to get a value is Aug-05 with a number of "4".

I know few about VBA and after searching around I found I can use `For ... Each` to loop in a range. But how do I get the index of the "v" in each loop? After I get that index, how do I get the value of the Date in the head row?

```
Function Get_Board_Count(range As range)
  For Each v In range
    ....
  Next
  Get_Board_Count = ....
End Function
```

Comment: which range in your sheet you want to use as a function `Range parameter`? which is best for you?

Comment: Why dont you just use a formula?

Comment: @brettdj I don't know what formula can achieve this.

Comment: Did any answer helps you solving your problem? If so, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can alternatively use an Excel-Only solution, which doesn't need VBA programming. Have a look a this formula:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2>0,0),0)))
```

`MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(A2:E2>0,0),0)` looks up the first value which is greater than 0 and not null and returns the current column index of this value. the rest of the formula refers to the row, with the dates, to get the wanted date per reference. In my case is it the first row...

Comment: +1 for an answer that doesn't need VBA. But note well that INDIRECT is a volatile function.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your advice. Do you know any better solution or replacement for the INDIRECT function in this case?

Comment: what is a "volatile function" - I've never heard that concept before. I searched but found most of the results are C/C++ related stuff.

Comment: Loosely speaking, a volatile function is one which, given that its outputs are not a deterministic function of its inputs, has to be recalculated each time the workbook is calculated. Today and rand are two familiar examples.

Answer (score 7):

```
Function Get_Board_Count(range As range)
    dim i as integer
    i = 1

    for each v in Range
       ...
       i = i + 1
    next


  Get_Board_Count = i 'Index of the item where cell is found.
End Function
```

Answer (score 4):

When using `For Each`, it's not a good idea to make any assumptions about the order in which you get the objects: it might change in subsequent Excel versions or even from session to session.

However, `v` is a reference to a range itself, so you have access to the properties and methods of Excel.Range via it. Use v.Column to extract the column to which a particular `v` is referring; which will be the column containing the corresponding date.

Comment: Thanks! I am familiar with JavaScript but very unfamiliar with VBA. Is there anything like `for (var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++)` in VBA for this case? Thanks!

Comment: Sadly not in the case. A range is not necessarily a vector or even a contiguous block.