# With For each loop in Excel VBA how do I reference the cell address within the formula?

Tags: vba, excel, foreach

The code I commented out originally required a user to drag down the formula once the formula was appended to a cell. I have revised the procedure below and I [switched from a `For each cell` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17587837/how-do-i-get-the-index-in-a-vba-for-each-loop-programming-with-excel) - could this have been done with a `For each` loop structure? Utilizing `Cell.address` or something along the lines? Please assume my variables are all defined.

```
Dim client_row As Long
'Dim v As Long
Dim v As Variant
Dim i As Integer
i = 2
client_row = 0

    LASTROW2 = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng2 = Range("N2:N" & LASTROW2)
'    For Each cell In rng2
'        If cell.Offset(0, -13) <> "" Then
'        cell.Formula = "=IFERROR(TEXT(IF(F2=""GBP"",($H2-(IF(LEN($C2)=7,BDH($C2&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH($C2&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/$H2/100,IF(E2=""EQ"",($H2-(IF(LEN($C2)=7,BDH($C2&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH($C2&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/$H2,($H2-(IF(LEN($C2)=7,BDH($C2&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH($C2&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/$H2*100)),""0.00""),""PLEASE REVIEW"")"
'        Debug.Print cell
'        End If
'     Next cell

     For Each v In rng2
             If v.Offset(0, -13) <> "" Then
        v.Formula = "=IFERROR(TEXT(IF($F" & i & "=""GBP"",($H2-(IF(LEN($C2)=7,BDH($C2&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH($C2&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/$H2/100,IF(E2=""EQ"",($H2-(IF(LEN($C2)=7,BDH($C2&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH($C2&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/$H2,($H2-(IF(LEN($C2)=7,BDH($C2&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH($C2&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/$H2*100)),""0.00""),""PLEASE REVIEW"")"
        i = i + 1
        Debug.Print i
        End If
     Next v
```

Comment: You can use specialcells to get non blank cells, then offset it to insert the formulas.`Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Offset(, 13).Formula = "=""MyFormula"""` Would that work, as the range should increment automatically

Comment: @Davesexcel Could you please provide an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you could use the `rng2.FormulaR1C1` property instead. It allows you to specify a [relative reference](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/formulaR1C1.html) which means you won't need to keep track of the current row.

The commented out section could be written as below:

```
Set rng2 = Range("N2:N" & LASTROW2)
For Each cell In rng2
    If cell.Offset(0, -13) <> "" Then
        cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(TEXT(IF(RC[-8]=""GBP"",(RC[-6]-(IF(LEN(RC[-11])=7,BDH(RC[-11]&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH(RC[-11]&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/RC[-6]/100,IF(RC[-9]=""EQ"",(RC[-6]-(IF(LEN(RC[-11])=7,BDH(RC[-11]&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH(RC[-11]&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/RC[-6],(RC[-6]-(IF(LEN(RC[-11])=7,BDH(RC[-11]&"" ""&""SEDOL"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()),BDH(RC[-11]&"" ""&""CUSIP"",""PX_LAST"",TODAY()))))/RC[-6]*100)),""0.00""),""PLEASE REVIEW"")"
        Debug.Print cell
    End If
 Next cell
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17587960/5636998) in your linked questions, you could also use `v.Column` to get the column of the current cell in the loop. There is no special structure like `For Each cell In range`. cell is in this scenario just an object variable pointing to a cell, just like `v` in your example.

To make your life a little bit easier just declare `v` as `Range`, then IntelliSense should show you possible properties and methods for `v`.

Luke's answer is another nice way to set relative addresses though ;)